# Append child directive within parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a parent directive where I want to dynamically add child directives in the link function. **The child directives ^require the parentDirective**.
I'm able to add any html element but as soon as I try to $compile my child directive I get the following error that it can't find the required controller. If I manually add the child directives it works perfectly.

Error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'myInput', required by directive 'myKey', can't be found!
```

My template should look like this after adding the elements:

```
<myInput>
 <myKey></myKey> <-- added dynamically
 <myKey></myKey> <-- added dynamically
 <myKey></myKey> <-- added dynamically
  ....
</myInput>
```

myInput directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myInput', ['$log', '$templateCache', '$compile', function($log, $templateCache, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      service: '=',            // expects a stimulus object provided by the tatoolStimulusService
      onkeydown: '&'           // method called on key press
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      this.addKey = function(keyCode, value) {
        $scope.service.addInputKey(keyCode, { givenResponse: value });
      };
    }],
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

      // add keys directives
      angular.forEach(scope.service.registeredKeyInputs, function(value, key) {
        var keyEl = angular.element(
          $compile('<myKey code="'+ key +'" response="'+ value.response +'"></myKey >')($rootScope));
        element.children(":first").append(keyEl);
      });

    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
}]);
```

myKey directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myKey', ['$log', '$sce', function($log, $sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    require: '^myInput',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, myCtrl) {
      myCtrl.addKey(attr.code, attr.response);

      // ...
    },
    template: '<div class="key"><span ng-bind-html="key"></span></div>'
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change the order of compile-append operations to append-compile:

```
var keyEl = angular.element('<myKey code="'+ key +'" response="'+ value.response +'"></myKey>');
element.append(keyEl);
$compile(keyEl)(scope);
```

Apparently it's important in this case (locating parent element directive), that new element being compiled was **already** in DOM.

Unless DOM element is appended to DOM it doesn't have a parent (its `parentNode` property is `null`). When Angular looks for `^myInput` it traverses up the DOM tree until it finds a node with required directive. If the element is not in DOM yet, this search fails immediately, because element doesn't have a single `parentNode`. Hence the error you are getting.

Also I recommend to change names of your directives from camelCase to snake-case:

```
<my-input>
    <my-key></my-key>
</my-input>
```

Then compiling part will also change:

```
angular.element('<my-key code="'+ key +'" response="'+ value.response +'"></my-key >');
```

Comment: That works perfectly and does even make sense (although documentation on this would help). I was only using dummy names in the post but you're right of course with the snake-case. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know about documentation, but it's easy to understand. Until DOM element is appended to DOM tree it **doesn't** have a parent (its `parentNode` property is `null`). When Angular looks for `^myInput` it traverses up the DOM tree until it find a node with required directive. In our case it fails immediately, because element doesn't have a single parentNode.